# View.setVisibility() crash with NPE at Android source code level

Tags: android

did some research for a while but couldn't find the reason for this. I'm setting `setVisibility()` on a view and it ends up with this stack trace:

```
android.view.View.setFlags (View.java:15721)
android.view.View.setVisibility (View.java:10789)
com.mypackage.SomeClass.updateVisibilityOfHeader()
```

So the crash doesn't happen because my View is null, it happens when updating the view internally. And this is the exception message (from Crashlytics on different Android versions):

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.invalidate(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

By looking at the `setFlags` method in `View` class source code I can see `invalidate` can be possibly called either on the parent of the view (which I also added null checks beforehand) or on the view itself. So if both the parent and the view are not null, what's the cause of this?

Any clue is much appreciated.

Edit: This is the method:

```
public void updateVisibilityOfHeader(boolean visible) {
    mHeader.animate().cancel();
    mHeader.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

As I said, the View itself is not null. And the crash doesn't happen on the `.setVisibility()` line, it happens inside that method.

Comment: Show us the part of your code, where the crash happens, please

Comment: Does the visibility change within a callback? Ex. showing a loading spinner, making a request to a server, the response is back, hiding spinner. Also, please post some code snippets

Comment: Sorry, now it should be a lot more clear.

Answer (score -1):

You need initialize view before call it.Or not properly initialize your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is initialized.

Comment: may be you initialize after call or  your id exist other in other view that why you not get error on writing time but run time.

Comment: exactly view is not null,If view was  null then you get error at first line means  here mHeader.animate().cancel()  not second line.may be  view is changing virtually .

Answer (score -1):

Because you never instantiated your view

add this in onCreate

```
yourView = findViewById(R.id.yourView);


yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

> GONE is a static field on the View class.
>
> If your code has import android.view.View, you reference GONE as
>   View.GONE.
>
> If your code has import static android.view.View.GONE